# Lambda Calculus Reductions

Tags: lambda, ocaml, lambda-calculus, reduction

I am able to do simple Lambda Calculus reductions however, I can not figure out how to do the ones that obtain **"currying"**.

These are the two examples that I cannot figure out:

1. `( ( ( lambda x . ( lambda y . ( j y ) ) ) j ) m )`
2. `( ( lambda p . ( p j ) ) ( lambda x . ( q x )))`

Comment: Just a comment: 2) is no example for currying, because there are no series of abstractions in there. It just reduces to ```p j``` in two steps.

Answer (score 2):

**Remark** There's a mistake with the evaluation, it reduces to `j m` instead, so the part about self-application isn't relevant.

Currying is the observation that you can view a series of lambda abstractions in different ways:

In mathematical terms, `( ( lambda x . ( lambda y . ( j y ) ) )` can be given a name and then written as: `f(x,y) = j(y)`. In your example, you would evaluate `f(m,j) = j(j)`. So what happens if we don't have both arguments for f? We can't evaluate it completely, but we can define a new function g(y) = f(j,y), where we just insert the first argument. This step-wise function evaluation is called partial evaluation or currying.

In lambda calculus, these two aspects look absolutely the same. If you want to apply both aruments to your term, you start with the first argument:

Your initial function f(m,j): `( ( ( lambda x . ( lambda y . ( j y ) ) ) j ) m )` reduces to g(j): `( ( lambda y . ( j y ) ) ) j`. When we continue our evaluation (we can still apply our function to j), we reach j(j): `j j`. Now we cannot apply any reduction rules anymore, so we could view `j j` as the result of our computation. That our result is an application is fine, but that it is applied to itself is something special.

(The rest is not related to currying anymore, but to self-application, which bridges to what @Matt was writing)

Perhaps one should explain what this means: the function j gets itself as argument. With this you can implement recursion. The famous Y combinator Y: `(lambda x . f x x)` does exactly that: if you evaluate `Y Y`, that is `(lambda x . f x x) Y`, you compute `f (Y Y)`. When you evaluate the inner `Y Y` again, you compute `f f (Y Y)` and so on. This is exactly a recursive application of the function `f`. A side-effect is that for some `f`, the evaluation will never terminate (already if you use the identity function `(lambda x.x)`).

Logicians in the mid-20th century wanted to use lambda-calculus as a data-structure, where infinite evaluation sequences should be forbidden. A possibility to restrict lambda calculus is that you give a type (quite similar to types in programming languages) to each variable. If you want to apply a variable to another one, the types need to fit.

E.g. suppose that `x` is of type `int`, then in the application `f x`, `f` needs to be of a type which takes a variable of type `int` and computes a result, let's say of type `string`. Then we can write the type of f as `int -> string`. The type of `f x` is `string`, since that's what we get when we evaluate f on x.

Abstractions create a new function. For instance `(lambda x . x)` needs an argument of type `int` and produces a term of type `int`, i.e. it is of type `int -> int`.

But now self-application like `j j` does not work anymore: say the inner j is of type `t`. Then the outer j must be of type `t -> t`. The only way to make this work is that your type is an infinite nesting of `t`, which is usually forbidden.

Even though this approach seems a little limited, you can add recursion on top of typed lambda calculus to build programming languages like Haskell or OCaml.

Comment: You say that `( ( ( lambda x . ( lambda y . ( j y ) ) ) j ) m )` reduces to `( ( lambda y . ( j y ) ) ) j`.  This is not correct.  You should be substituting the `x` for the `j`, which would reduce to `( ( lambda y . ( j y ) ) m ) ` as I have in my answer.  Try running `( ( (\x -> (\y -> 1 + y) ) ) 1 ) 3` through GHC, it will come out to 4, not 3...

Comment: Argl you are right, thanks for pointing it out. I had the parenthesis wrong ( ```(\x -> (\y -> 1+y) 1 ) 3``` instead). I'll fix my answer when i have proper internet access again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about the simply typed lambda calculus using a call by value evaluation strategy, The first one reduces likes this:

1. ( ( ( lambda x . ( lambda y . ( j y ) ) ) j ) m )  -- substitute `x` for `j`
2. ( ( lambda y . ( j y ) )  m )  -- substitute `y` for `m`
3. ( j m )
4. From here, you are stuck...

There is typically no reduction rule for applying a variable to a variable.  This is generally why we use a type system, to ensure that for any well-typed program, when we evaluate we never "get stuck" as we did in step 3.

Currying shouldn't add any additional complexity than what you might have already seen.  In general the strategy form something of the form `e1 e2 ... en`, you can think of it as `(((e1 e2) e3) ... en)`.  You are then going to reduce `e1 e2`, which should yield a lambda, which you than evaluate applied to `e3` and so on.

I'll let you figure out the second one as an exercise.

Comment: A type system doesn't prevent applications from variable to variable, it only prevents self-application. E.g. ```(\ x y.x) (f 0) 0``` is typable with 0,x,y of type t and f of type t->t. Even nestings are not excluded: ```f (g f)``` can be typed with f: ```s->t``` and g : ```(s -> t) -> s``` .

Comment: My claim was not that the purpose of a type system is to rule out programs that will apply variables to variables.  My claim was that the purpose of a type system is to ensure that when a well-typed program is evaluated, it doesn't "get stuck" as we did in step 3.  I'll admit that my wording was perhaps a bit ambiguous and I will happily fix that.  However, to say that a type system **ONLY** prevents self-application is not a correct statement.